# Which tags are can be self closing and which ones must have a closing tag in XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: xhtml, tags, strict

Which tags are can be self closing and which ones must have a closing tag in XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Example:

```
<br/>
<input />
```

Are there certain tags that must have a closing tag, can be self closing, or eigther way works in XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every element, that’s content model is `EMPTY` in the [XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict) (i.e. `<!ELEMENT element-name EMPTY>`), is an [empty element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6) and “must either have an end tag or the start tag must end with `/>`.” Namely it’s `base`, `meta`, `link`, `hr`, `br`, `param`, `img`, `area`, and `input`. Every other element must have an end tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about "EMPTY Elements" including `<hr /> <input /> <img /> <meta /> <link />`  which can all be closed in a single tag. Non-empty elements which should contain text or sub-elements could technically be closed this way if they have no child or text but you are not supposed to do it.  For example `<p></p>` should not be `<p />` but that could pass strict validation.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines